# Text encoding in HTML text fields

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have a site up that has a form on it. The form POSTs to a php script which then inserts the data into my database. The page has a charset=UTF-8 attribute in the <meta> tag, and the database is setup to use UTF-8. However, when I copy and paste characters from MS Word into the field, the output is messed up.

For example, the quotes in

I am using "Microsoft Word" ''''

become

I am using â€œMicrosoft Wordâ€ ????

in the database.

Anyone have any idea why this might occur?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I propose you do to find where the problem lies.

1. MySQL uses charset *Latin1* to store and transfer in/out data per default. To change that, do the following. Create your database with charset UTF8/collation utf8_unicode_ci (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html).

   `CREATE DATABASE example
   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
   DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
2. Tell MySQL to handle in/out data as UTF8. Before any SQL queries are sent to MySQL the command SET NAMES UTF8; must be made. This tells MySQL to accept and handle all in/out data to the server as UTF8. This needs to be set only once per connection. You can set this with `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` for example.
3. Make sure you're actually using UTF8. Altough you might have specified UTF8 in the `<meta>` tag, you might acually be sending the content in another charset. To make sure you're sending UTF8 encoded content, add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

run `set names utf8` query and get rid of all recoding functions in your code

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but a suggestion. First try the grandma (30 sec) test: paste the MS Word text you want to copy into a good text-editor like editpad pro or notepad++ if everything appear as expected copy It again **from there** and paste It inside your form.

In other words don't copy and past a text directly from MS WORD.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simple java webapp that didn't specify any character set or encodings anywhere, and run into the same problems.  In my case, the following changes produced the desired behavior:

1. Change db schema definition to use UTF-8 (using MySQL).
2. Change db connector URL to specify UTF-8 in connection URL (using MySQL Connector-J)
3. Change app server configuration to interpret request parameter data as UTF-8.
4. Change all generated HTML pages to specify UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting from a `<textarea>` or a WYSIWYG form? The WYSIWYG JavaScript could be doing its own encoding.

Have you tried it in different browsers? It could be a bug with a particular browser. Also, try setting the headers in PHP, instead of with a meta tag, as your server may be sending conflicting headers.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

What happens if you save the $_POST data to a file? Does the encoding look OK?

```
file_put_contents('post.log', print_r($_POST, true));
```

Then what happens if you copy the text from Word into a text file and insert the file's contents into the database?

```
$db_query = 'INSERT INTO table SET col="' . mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents('input.txt')) . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<form action="form_action.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```