# PHP: Updating with öäå into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I already have done this:

`mysql_set_charset("utf8",$link);` at the connection

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` at the connection + on every table in database

changing from latin1 to utf8 collation + character for every table + columns

file have meta utf8 + `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` plus the files itself are formatted in utf-8( without bom)

where link is mysql_connect(), it shows the öäå characters fine when i take them out from database, but when i try to mysql_query UPDATE with stuff, that contains ÖÄÅ, it stores as Ã?Â¶Ã .. How can i fix this?

In the database the columns and so are, latin1_swedish_ci, as said it INSERT ÖÄÅs without problem, and echo it out too very well, but not when i try to UPDATE SET $user = 'ööö'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'") on every table in database

can you be more specific? I see no way to use this *query* on every table.

> it stores as Ã?Â¶Ã ..

how do you check it?

Comment: Sorry, i found the problem, and its in a foreach, nothing at all about this, my fault i thought the foreach() could not do anything to the ÖÄÅ chars.. Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645668/php-foreach-dont-understand-oaa

Answer (score 0):

> In the database the columns and so are, latin1_swedish_ci

This is your problem. You need to use a UTF-8 character set to store UTF-8 data.

What you are showing: `Ã?Â¶Ã` is most likely UTF-8 data (which can consist of multiple bytes) being stored in a latin1 table.

Comment: @Karem do you use a front-end like phpMyAdmin to insert the data? phpMyAdmin can detect and deal with character set differences.

Comment: Dont really know what front-end is, but ok, ill try to change my columns to utf8 now

Comment: is there any way i could do this to them all fast, instead of going one column by one?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin as you said

Comment: @Karem II thought there was an easy way of editing multiple columns at once, but I can't remember right now, and I don't have phpMyAdmin handy. It might be in there somewhere.

Comment: Ok but i just did one quick check to make sure it really was that. I changed one column to utf8_swedish_ci collation, and utf8 character, and then i made a query("update set column1 = 'ÖÄÅ' i still get that strange characters?

Comment: @Karem is your incoming form (or wherever you type in the data) encoded as UTF-8 as well?

Comment: @Pekka not much knowledge but i do have it set with mysql_set_charset("utf8",$link); as said in the question. The file are UTF8, where i have the query..

Comment: @Karem your HTML files need to be UTF8 encoded as well. I'm off now, but this question will give you everything you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662885/text-encoding-in-html-text-fields 'night!

Comment: ok, everything in my database is not collating and char utf8, i have mysql_set_charset("utf8",$link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); for the connection, and header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); + meta + file itself encoded in utf8 and still those chars

Comment: actually a table/columns collation doesn't matter as long as it supports all stored characters.