# Problems with characters like ÖÄÅ

Tags: php, character-encoding

My form

```
<form action="saveProfile.php" method="post" name="ProfileUpdate" id="ProfileUpdate" >
<input name="Smeknamn" id="Smeknamn" type="text" value="<?php echo $v["user_name"]; ?>" maxlength="16" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_cphContentLeft_tbUsername" onkeydown="return ((event.keyCode != 16) || (event.keyCode == 16 &amp;&amp; this.value.length >= 1));" style="width: 130px;" />
</form>
```

When I try to `echo $_POST["Smeknamn"];` on saveProfile.php i get `Ã�Ã�Ã�` on the characters `Ö Ä Å`

Why is this happening? `saveProfile` AND `editProfile` is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, and meta utf8 and all that.

**UPDATE** UPDATE

$smeknamn = $data["Smeknamn"]

Sorry forgot to mention that i had this foreach.
And its $smeknamn im echoing and getting Ã�Ã�Ã�.
I just tried $_POST["Smeknamn"] and it echo out ÖÄÅ just fine.. So the problem is now in the foreach() that makes the öäå chars Ã�Ã�Ã�. How can i fix this?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered moving some of that inline Javascript to a separate script file?

Comment: In the future, please consider adding that info to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644359/php-updating-with-oaa-into-mysql) instead of creating a duplicate.

Comment: @Karem - the `onkeydown` attribute contains javascript.

Comment: Does your html have a meta tag that specifies the encoding?

Comment: Sorry the question has been updated, i found out exactly the problem now. Please check it.

Comment: What if you remove htmlentities? If your file is UTF8 encoded you need to change the encoding for htmlentities, read http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php on how to change.

Comment: You should not use this universal-like filter function because each language/context has its own special characters that need to be taken care of.

Comment: gumbo my webpage im making is only for my language, so i dont need other special characters than these. Marwelln, so if i get this right i need to change the line to $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)), UTF-8); ?

Comment: @Marwelln , Just tried, yes it works ÖÄÅ without the htmlentities! Shouldnt i have htmlentities, or how do i have it with UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue.

I guess your data is actually encoded with UTF-8 so the character `Ö` (U+00D6) is encoded with 0xC396. Now when [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) is called without specifying the *charset* parameter, it implicitly uses ISO 8859-1:

> […] optional third argument *`charset`* which defines character set used in conversion. Presently, the ISO-8859-1 character set is used as the default.

And when interpreting the byte sequence 0xC396 with ISO 8859-1 it represents the two ISO 8859-1 characters 0xC3 and 0x96. Since there is the entity *Atilde* for the ISO 8859-1 character 0xC3, this character is replaced by `htmlentities` with the reference `&Atilde;`. But there isn’t any entity representing the second character 0x96, so it’s not being replaced. That means:

```
htmlentities("\xC3\x96") === "&Atilde;\x96"
```

Now when this is interpreted by the user agent, the character reference gets displayed correctly but the remaining byte 0x96 is not a valid byte sequence for a character in UTF-8. That’s why the replacement character `�` is displayed instead.

So the problem is that you didn’t specify the correct character encoding for `htmlentities`:

```
htmlentities("\xC3\x96", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") === "&Ouml;"
```

But as you’re already using UTF-8 for your output, you don’t need to replace such characters and using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead will suffice to replace the HTML special characters.

But besides that, you shouldn’t use such an universal-like filter function as every language and context has its own special character that need to be taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding `editProfile.php` and `saveProfile.php` as UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: +1: Does indeed look like encoding confusion. In particular, it looks like saveProfile.php is echoing UTF-8 encoded data yet declaring it is something else, such as ISO 8859-1. Note that the **default** encoding is ISO 8859-1. Lots of people still seem to get this wrong, and the bodges by browser makers around this don't help either. Ugh.

Comment: Sorry please check my updated question, my fault i didnt mention the foreach loop, it was not the encoding..